# How to create an .app file in mac os x from binaries?

Tags: python, macos

I have a project in the form of binaries which can be distributed to other mac pcs.
How to create an .app file for that project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html), it might solve your problem.

> py2app is a Python setuptools command which will allow you to make standalone application bundles and plugins from Python scripts. py2app is similar in purpose and design to py2exe for Windows.